# \mintinline double-renders # symbol in footnote

Tags: minted, code

I'm using `minted` to display inline code in a footnote. For some reason the # symbol is rendered twice.
This does not happen outside of footnotes.

```
\footnote{bla bla \mintinline{python}{x = 5 # text} and so on}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated in the first footnote on page 8 of [`minted` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/minted/minted.pdf),

> The command (`\mintinline`) has been carefully crafted so that in most cases it will function correctly when used inside other commands.<sup>1</sup>
>
> <sup>1</sup> For example, `\mintinline` works in footnotes! The main exception is when the code contains the percent `%` or hash `#` characters, or unmatched curly braces.

The following trick tries to handle `#`:

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minted}

\makeatletter
\let\footnote@orig\footnote
\def\footnote{%
  \begingroup
  \@makeother\#%
  \footnote@i
}
% added \long to accept multi-para footnotes
\long\def\footnote@i#1{%
  \endgroup
  \footnote@orig{#1}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
content\footnote{bla bla \mintinline{python}{x = 5 # text} and so on}
\end{document}
```

Updates:

- Apr 3, 2022 Made `\footnote@i` long, cf [@cgnieder
  's comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/549568/mintinline-double-renders-symbol-in-footnote/549579#comment1593971_639486).

Answer (score 2):

For information, if you use the package `piton` in order to format Python listings, you won't have this problem (however `\piton` works only with LuaLaTeX).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{piton}

\begin{document}

Some text.\footnote{bla bla \piton{x = 5 # text} and so on}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

The colors are the colors are the style `manni` of Pygments (and `minted`).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with double-hash rendering in beamer slides. Adding the attribute `fragile` to the frame solved my problem.